# How to iterate through array from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have an entery in a MySQL table that looks similar to this...

```
1234567899, 3216549877, 6549873211, 9876543214, 1472583699
```

... and when I retrieve it with PHP it comes back as ...

```
Array([0] => 1234567899, 3216549877, 6549873211, 9876543214, 1472583699)
```

I shouldn't have any trouble with this, but my brain is farting and I can't figure it out! How do I get the individual values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exploding the value should do the trick:

http://php.net/explode

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) an example that would work for you is this:

```
$mysql_result = "1234567899, 3216549877, 6549873211, 9876543214, 1472583699";
$array = explode(", ",$mysql_result);

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    echo $value."<br />";
    //$value will equal each of the elements that are seperate by a comma and a space above
}
/*

Result will look like this:
1234567899
3216549877
6549873211
9876543214
1472583699
*/
```